# What is the normal format for files on ubuntu ?

Tags: 14.04, mount, partitioning

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I'm so new to it as I was using windows before.

As poeple told me I need three partitions ( Swap , ext4 , partition for normal files and folders ) it was recommended to me to make the third partition's format **NTFS** but it actually askes me to mount it every time I boot up my laptop over and over again .

My question is "Is there any other format which is used for normal data for ubuntu or Is there any solution for it ?"

My thanks in advance .

Comment: The 3 partition set up is unnecessary, it's sufficient to have one partition for your root filesystem ( in windows terms it's `C:\ `  ) and swap( virtual memory , extends RAM ).  It has been suggested because 3rd partition can help you separate files , and in case disk fails, 3rd partition should be safe. But it's really unnecessary.

Comment: The "normal" filesystem type for Ubuntu is (at least for the moment) ext4: the reason you may have been advised to use a separate NTFS partition is for the case of a dual-boot setup in which you want to access the same files via Windows **and** Linux

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the NTFS partition to be mounted automatically on boot. That can be done by adding info about your partition to `/etc/fstab` file, which is basically a list of disks/filesystems (and also respective options for those disks and filesystems, like read-write, read only, etc) that get mounted automatically during boot sequence.

To do that , open Terminal ( in Windows' terms that's CMD or PowerShell ), run `sudo blkid` command. There will be output for each partition; find the `UUID` for your NTFS partition.

Sample output,

```
 /dev/sdb2: LABEL="TI105866W0A" UUID="4EBAAE53BAAE36FD" TYPE="ntfs"
```

For instance, if I wanted to have `/dev/sdb2` mounted automatically (which is my windows partition on another disk ), I need that  UUID="4EBAAE53BAAE36FD" part.

Next , open for writing `/etc/fstab` file in text editor, with admin priviledges ( in other words add `sudo` or `gksu` before calling the editor, e.g., `sudo nano /etc/fstab` ). and add a line in the format as shown bellow

```
UUID=1234-abcd-5678-efgh   /media/myMountPoint  ntfs defaults 0 1
```

`/media/myMountPoint` has to exist as a directory, so I suggest you make a new directory with `sudo mkdir /media/myMountPoint`

Note that opening the `/etc/fstab` file with root permissions, can also be done graphically with `gksu gedit` or `pkexec gedit`. Personally, i prefer command line editors `vim` or `nano`

For more info refer to [MountingWindowsPartitions Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions#Configuring_.2Fetc.2Ffstab)

Comment: I'm actually not fully understanding you Serg can you make it simpler because I'm totally new to ubuntu stuff

Comment: @Meyer edited my answer, please review